# How to get a Generic response from Retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am creating a wrapper for Retrofit. The interface looks like this

```
public interface OkRetroInterface {

    @GET
    retrofit2.Call<OkRetroType> get(@Url String Url);

    @POST
    retrofit2.Call<OkRetroType> post(@Url String Url);
}
```

OkRetroType is just an implementation of the Type interface.

```
public class OkRetroType implements Type {

}
```

What I want to do is allow a user to input a URL and the Class for the expected JSON response and return the user the parsed response on successful call and handle the error otherwise. So how should I define the interface that takes the class for the expected JSON, the URL for the API and return the expected object.

The main thing I need to solve is to dynamically set the type of response I am going to get, i.e., set up OkRetroType at runtime.